# How to populate forms in formset with model data?

Tags: python, django

I got Questions and Answers as models. So on one page users can create a new question and some answers for it. To do so a QuestionModelForm will be loaded and a formset with the desired number of AnswerModelForms:

```
class AnswerCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answertext = forms.CharField(max_length=500, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "max"}), label="Antworttext")
    field_order = ["answertext", "iscorrect"]
```

```
#views.py
AnswerFormSet = formset_factory(AnswerCreateForm, extra=ac)
formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST)

#html template
<form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_data }}
        {{ formset.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="add question." />
</form>
```

This formset will be send to the html-Template. So far no problem. Now I want to add the option for the user to edit previously created questions and their answers. When one goes to the edit page I want the same forms loaded as before, but prepopulated with the data of the object to edit. With the question form its no problem, cause I can just do

```
form_question = QuestionCreateForm(instance=question)
```

How can I do the same with my formset for the answers? There will be a query to the DB which loads all answer-objects for that question. Then I want to create a formset with the amount of forms as answers were returned and each of those populated with the answer data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You populate these with the [**`queryset=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) which is the counterpart of the `instance=…` parameter for a `ModelForm`:

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory

answers = question.answer_set.all()
AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Answer, form=AnswerCreateForm, extra=ac)
formset = AnswerFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=answers)
```

You do the same when you create a form for rendering:

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory

answers = question.answer_set.all()
AnswerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Answer, form=AnswerCreateForm, extra=ac)
formset = AnswerFormSet(queryset=answers)
```

Comment: I guess I have to use a modelformset_factory then? Because in your example with the formset_factory I get "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset".

Comment: @Morb: ah, yes, otherwise it does not make much sense, since a simple Form has nothing to do with a model, only a `ModelForm` has.

Comment: Alright, got it working now. It has to be `modelformset_factory(Answer, form=AnswerCreateForm)` though, cause the modeformset_factory needs defined fields. Thanks for your help.